# How can I run 2 loops simultaneously in python?

Tags: python, gtk

I have an application (Gtk) that has an embedded server (using circuits). Both components (The GUI and Server) have infinite loops. How can I run both loops simultaneously ?

I also need the server loop to end when the gtk loop ends.

The code for the example server

```
from circuits.web import Server, Controller
import os

class MyServer(Controller):

    def index(self):

        return "Hello World"


server = Server(8000)
server += MyServer()
server.run()
```

and the code for example gtk application

```
import gtk

class App:

    def __init__(self):

        self.window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
        self.window.connect("destroy",gtk.main_quit)
        self.window.show_all()

        gtk.main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
```

Comment: You need to choose one of the loops, and run the other from within it. I'm not sure the circuits framework has it, but the gtk has a function that executes the inside of the main loop once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) module to do this:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def run_app():
    ... run the app ...

def run_server():
    ... run the server ...

def main():
    app = Process(target=run_app)
    app.start()

    server = Process(target=run_server)
    server.start()

    app.join()
    server.terminate()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Otherwise, if you're using Python < 2.6 on Unix, you could fiddle around with `os.fork()` to do the same sort of thing. [Threading](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html) *might* work, but I don't know how well GTK or circuits plays with threads.

Comment: Also take a look at stackless python http://www.stackless.com/. It's designed to be able to run many concurrent tasks just like this. I've never used it, but it looks cool. Not sure if it will work with gtk apps or not.

Answer (score 1):

You could run the web server from another thread:

```
from threading import Thread

# ...

server = Server(8000)
server += MyServer()

web_server_thread = Thread(target=server.run)
web_server_thread.start()

gtk.main()
```

Comment: Threading doesn't work for me dunno why. I was trying to figure out how it works all the day but couldn't get it to work for my case as I am unable to understand it. Will try your example though. Thanx a lot.